# Silverlight Toolkit - ChildWindow with Theme

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, silverlight-toolkit

From a silverlight forum page I found, I was under the impression that a ChildWindow created in the code behind *would* pick up the theme of the rest of the page; it's only when you *inherit* from ChildWindow that this no longer is the case.

For some reason though this is not happening for me.  Here is my theme element:

```
<wp:Theme x:Name="ThemeContainer" ThemeUri="/System.Windows.Controls.Theming.BubbleCreme;component/Theme.xaml">
```

And here's the event handler for a button that I'm using to try to create a ChildWindow.  The window pops up, but does not have any theme applied:

```
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
        ChildWindow cw = new ChildWindow() { Height = 250, Width = 200 };
        cw.Show();
    }
```

Is there any way to get this to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to set your desired global theme in the **App.xaml** and declare it as the Application's theme:

```
<Application xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
             x:Class="MyApp"
             xmlns:thm="MyThemeNamespace"
             thm:MyTheme.IsApplicationTheme="True"
             >
    <Application.Resources>

    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

To set the application theme dynamically, you can try the static

```
Theme.SetApplicationThemeUri(myApp, myThemeUri);
```

Comment: Bah - if I do that, will I still be able to dynamically switch themes while the app is running like I can with the theme declared on the page??

Comment: That worked perfectly.  I don't even need anything in the app.xaml file.  Just setting Theme.SetApplicationThemeUri(myApp, myThemeUri) in my code behind was what I needed.  I'm trying to do the classic combobox 'o themes that the user can choose from.